# Django - Get Variable in Junction Table - ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I use Django with a MySQL database and create my models with `python manage.py inspectdb`...but a well known problem is to manage junction table (n-n). Django propose ManyToManyField object but i stuck specific problem...

## Models

```
class A(models.Model):
    id_A = models.AutoField(db_column='idA', primary_key=True)
    to_B = models.ManyToManyField(
        'B',
        through='A_has_B',
    )

class B(models.Model):
    id_B = models.AutoField(db_column='idB', primary_key=True)
    to_A = models.ManyToManyField(
        A,
        through='A_has_B',
    )

class A_has_B(models.Model):
    A_id_A = models.ForeignKey(A, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='A_idA')
    B_id_B = models.ForeignKey(B, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='B_idB')
    variable_i_want = models.CharField(db_column='variable_i_want', max_length=45)
```

## Example case

I loop my A object model like this :

```
for a in A.objects.all():
    # Here i want to get the variable : variable_i_want
    variable_i_want = ?????????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all related  `A_has_B` objects using reverse relation:

```
for a in A.objects.all():
    a_has_b_list = a.a_has_b_set.all()  # return all related objects
    for a_has_b in a_has_b_list:  
        variable_i_want = a_has_b.variable_i_want
```

Note that `A_id_A = models.ForeignKey(A, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='A_idA')` creates [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) manager which you can access from `A` object. By default name of this reverse relation attribute is lovercased model name appended with `_set` prefix `a_has_v_set` in your case. But you can control this name by using [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) argument.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I follow your tips and i get stuck with that error `(1054, "Unknown column 'A_has_B.id' in 'field list'")` at the `a_has_b_list = a.a_has_b_set.all()` code line

Comment: @DalinDad I suppose this is because you `A_has_B` doesn't have primary key field. You should add since in django `Each model requires exactly one field to have primary_key=True (either explicitly declared or automatically added).` Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Comment: Yeah is bit complicate for add primary key field in n-n table `just` for django. this is not the best action in regard of the database performance.